# Data backdrop in true not working Angular 6

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, angular6

I have a problem with this attribute data-backdrop in my modal of bootstrap 4, because not working as expected. What should happen is that when you click outside of modal, it closes, however, this does not happen. I'm using angular 6:

I have tried adding the data backdrop attribute to true but it still does not work

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalUser" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalUserLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false" data-keyboard="false">
    <app-modal-user (inviteUser)="appendUser($event)" [users]="users" [typeUser]="typeUser" ></app-modal-user>
</div>
```

Currently when you click outside it does not work. It should be noted that the data-keyboard attribute does work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation is stated that the default is true and it's action is by default to close the modal on click outside the modal. You are disabling that and that's why it's not closing the modal. Remove the `data-backdrop` or set it to true if you really want...and then the modal will close when clicking outside the modal.

See --> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#options

More over the options can be passed along the initialization if you are doing that the JS way (in your angular 6 component) check to see if you are not overwriting the configuration given with attributes .

See --> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modaloptions